# Jquery pass this.Text() as identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically im just trying to get the value of this.Text() and edit css of all class with that value.

```
<div>
     <img class="First" style="display:none">
     <img class="Second" style="display:none">
     <img class="Third" style="display:none">
     <p><span class="firstWord">First</span> phrase</p>
</div>

<div>
     <img class="First" style="display:none">
     <img class="Second" style="display:none">
     <img class="Third" style="display:none">
     <p><span class="firstWord">Second</span> phrase</p>
</div>

<div>
     <img class="First" style="display:none">
     <img class="Second" style="display:none">
     <img class="Third" style="display:none">
     <p><span class="firstWord">Third</span> phrase</p>
</div>
```

Im using this code to get the first word but im a bit lost on how to pass this.Text as indentifier. Im just trying to unhide an image with a class the same with the value of `this.Text()` :

```
$('.firstWord').each(function() { 
     fwtext = $(this).text();
     $('#' $fwtext).css("display", "block");
});
```

The div and all tags inside it are dynamically generated and repeated so i cant simply go on editing them.

THANK YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE FOR HELPING.

Comment: There is no attribute `display` for html tags. You should replace it with `style="display: none;"`. Then: you have `fwtext` variable, not `$fwtext`. In your case variable `fwtext` declared as global - be careful. And finally: there is a mistake in your jQuery selector. It should looks like `$("#" + fwText)`.

Comment: Yep. Thanks. i didnt notice i typed it that way.

Comment: And forget to notice that you should select necessary `img` by CSS-class with `.` selector, not by `id` with `#` selector. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `img` tags have a class, not an id. So your jQuery selector should look like: `$("." + fwtext)`. And yes - it will display necessary image only in corresponding `div`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q60jrdjq/2/) for testing.

```
$(".firstWord").each(function () {
    var fwtext = $(this).text();
    var currentBlock = $(this).parents("div");
    currentBlock.find("." + fwtext).show();
});
```

Comment: @James I've updated jsFiddle. Since your `div`s can have different first words as selectors - it shows image with classname taken from `firstWord` inside current `div`.

Comment: Thanks i saw it but its still showing all images. maybe theres a conflict with my other scripts

Comment: @James It is really strange. Look at this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q60jrdjq/3/)

Comment: @James Well, you didn't provide actual markup in your question. So... For your test page just replace `var currentBlock = $(this).parents("div");` with `var currentBlock = $(this).parents(".custom-product");`. And do not forget to add `style="display: none;"` for all necessary images.

Comment: Thanks so much. i got it figured out now.

Comment: I only provided a short copy of the code. since almost all of it is system generated. Thank so much for helping.

Comment: @James I understand, but our answers are based on your question's code snippet which has only one parent `div` for every block without any ids or classes. That was a reason for some misunderstandings =). You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks. Will include more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
 $('#' + $fwtext)
//-----^
```

Add a `+` for concatenation. Also since you are using a `class` and not an `id`, you must use `.` instead of `#`:

```
 $('.' + $fwtext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` sign and add `+` in place of it

```
 $('#'+ fwtext).css("display", "block");
```

based on your comment here is the edit

```
$('.firstWord').each(function() { 
     $('<div></div>').text($(this).text()).css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the divs and child tags are dynamically generated, so the script need to cycle to all .firstWord class. The problem is it keeps on showing the same image in all divs

Comment: try this 
$('.firstWord').each(function() { 
     $('<div></div>').text($(this).text()).css("display", "block");
});

Comment: thanks but nope. it took all other child out and left the first word.